# Issue in Returning Value in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

I am facing an issue while returning value.

This is my function from where I am returning value:

```
async function createOrderId(bizId) {
    const CustomerOrderModel = require('../models/CustomerOrder');
    try {
        var biz_id = bizId;
        var year = new Date().getFullYear();
        var total = 0;
        total = await CustomerOrderModel.countDocuments({bizId:bizId}).exec();
        var w_order_id = biz_id + 'OD' + year + (total+1);
        return w_order_id;
    } catch (e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

And in some another API I have called this function and want this w_order_id. but I am not getting value.

**Note:** When I am calling this function, I also tried to use async & await to resolve this issue. But still not getting value.

Kindly help me.

Comment: can you share postman ?

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `w_order_id` within the function to confirm it's not an issue with the network layer of your application?

Answer (score 0):

Try it by using Promise

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        var biz_id = bizId;
        var year = new Date().getFullYear();
        var total = 0;
        total = await CustomerOrderModel.countDocuments({bizId:bizId}).exec((err, result)=>{
            if(err){
              reject(err)
            } else {
           var w_order_id = biz_id + 'OD' + year + (total+1);
           resolve(w_order_id);
        }

    });

})
```